# best way to preserve space around anchors in bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-5

I've noticed that the spaces that normally occur (case 1 below) on either side of an anchor disappear when they're centred within a flexbox (case 2).

I was able correct this by adding &nbsp; on either side (case 3) but this seems ugly.  Is there a better way?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <h1>Sample Page</h1>
    <div>
        Case 1: This is a <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">link</a> to Google
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        Case 2: This is a second <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">link</a> to Google
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        Case 3: This is a third&nbsp;<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">link</a>&nbsp;to Google
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do 2 things:

1. Add a flex gap, by adding the class `gap-x` (where x can be anything ranging 0-5) to your div with `d-flex`. This will add a space between all elements of the flex.
2. You can add a class `px-1` to the `a` tag itself. It'll add a padding on left and right of the anchor tag without affecting other spaces.

Comment: gap-1 worked well for me as I have a few anchors within a centred footer